# SQL Where with Binary(n) column

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateOrInsertNotification]
    @ContentJsonHash BINARY(32)
AS
    DECLARE @NotificationId INT;

    SET @NotificationId = (SELECT @NotificationId
                           FROM dbo.tblNotifications n
                           WHERE n.ContentJsonHash = @ContentJsonHash);

    IF @NotificationId IS NOT NULL  
    BEGIN
        -- Increment Count
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         -- Insert new row.
    END
```

It's supposed to check if the Hash already exists and if it does, increment the count for the row, otherwise insert the row. However, it never finds the Hash and the corresponding `NotificationId`. `NotificationId` is always null.

If I run it twice, passing it the same data (a C# array `byte[32]`). It never finds the same `NotificationId` and I end up with duplicate entries being put in.

e.g.

```
NotificationId | ContentJsonHash
9                0xB966C33517993003D789EDF78DA20C4C491617F8F42F76F48E572ACF8EDFAC2A
10               0xB966C33517993003D789EDF78DA20C4C491617F8F42F76F48E572ACF8EDFAC2A
```

Can I not do comparisons on Binary(n) fields like this `WHERE n.ContentJsonHash = @ContentJsonhash` ?

The C# code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Sql.ConnectionString))
{
     await conn.OpenAsync();

     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql.SqlUpdateOrInsertNotification, conn))
     {
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", notificationMessage.Source);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sender", notificationMessage.Sender);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NotificationType", notificationMessage.NotificationType);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceivedTimestamp", notificationMessage.Timestamp);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentJSon", notificationMessage.NotificationContent);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentJsonHash", notificationMessage.ContentHashBytes);

          await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

I've also tried calling the stored procedure from SQL like this:

```
exec dbo.spUpdateOrInsertNotification 'foo', 'bar',  0, 
                                      '2017-12-05 15:23:41.207', '{}',
                              0xB966C33517993003D789EDF78DA20C4C491617F8F42F76F48E572ACF8EDFAC2A
```

Calling this twice returns 2 rows :(

I can do this, which works, hard coding the binary field I want to check

```
select *
from dbo.tblNotifications
where ContentJsonhash = 0xB966C33517993003D789EDF78DA20C4C491617F8F42F76F48E572ACF8EDFAC2A
```

Comment: That should be perfectly fine. What exact type is the column and how do you call the sp from C#?

Comment: (Also bear in mind that a row could be inserted in-between you reading into @NotificationId and then using it)

Comment: @Alex K. I've added the C# and also calling it from sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an @ where I shouldn't have had an ampersand.

```
SET @NotificationId = (SELECT @NotificationId
                       FROM dbo.tblNotifications n
                       WHERE convert(varchar(32), n.ContentJsonHash, 2) = convert(varchar(32), @ContentJsonHash, 2));
```

Should be

```
SET @NotificationId = (SELECT NotificationId
                       FROM dbo.tblNotifications n
                       WHERE convert(varchar(32), n.ContentJsonHash, 2) = convert(varchar(32), @ContentJsonHash, 2));
```

I feel so stupid for not noticing this sooner :(

Answer (score 1):

Binary comparisons can be tricky. If you are using a true binary column, I believe length also comes into play. So even if those bytes are the same, and the lengths differ, the comparison would be false. An easy way is to convert these to strings:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[spUpdateOrInsertNotification]
    @ContentJsonHash BINARY(32)
AS

DECLARE @NotificationId INT;
SET @NotificationId = (SELECT NotificationId
                       FROM dbo.tblNotifications n
                       WHERE convert(varchar(32), n.ContentJsonHash, 2) = convert(varchar(32), @ContentJsonHash, 2));

IF @NotificationId IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN
   -- Increment Count
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- Insert new row.
END
```